# google drive save button and cors with headers

Tags: php, google-drive-api, cors

I'm trying to make "save to drive" button on my site using [Google Drive Web APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/savetodrive#asynchronous_javascript_loading), but no results. After clicking on button there are errors like this:

```
*XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://myFILEsiteONE/file.doc. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://myMAINsiteTWO' is therefore not allowed access.*
```

At stackoverflow have a lot of answers about this: all problems solved by headers, which described at google documentation.

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Cache-Control, Content-Encoding, Content-Range
```

But my site already have this headers. There is result of `get_headers` php function:

```
array{
['0'] => string'HTTP/1.1 200 OK'
['1'] => string'Server: nginx'
['2'] => string'Date: Tue, 23 Dec 2014 13:41:52 GMT'
['3'] => string'Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8'
['4'] => string'Content-Length: 1643'
['5'] => string'Connection: close'
['6'] => string'Vary: Accept-Encoding'
['7'] => string'X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3'
['8'] => string'P3P: policyref="/bitrix/p3p.xml", CP="NON DSP COR CUR ADM DEV PSA PSD OUR UNR BUS UNI COM NAV INT DEM STA"'
['9'] => string'X-Powered-CMS: Bitrix Site Manager (bc446669bda3fecf3857134c6da9af3b)'
['10'] => string'Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=2ujm04isb6h1e3tk2ddonr4537; path=/; HttpOnly'
['11'] => string'Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT'
['12'] => string'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0'
['13'] => string'Pragma: no-cache'
['14'] => string'Set-Cookie: BITRIX_SM_GUEST_ID=256066; expires=Fri, 18-Dec-2015 13:41:12 GMT; path=/'
['15'] => string'Set-Cookie: BITRIX_SM_LAST_VISIT=23.12.2014+16%3A41%3A12; expires=Fri, 18-Dec-2015 13:41:12 GMT; path=/'
['16'] => string'Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *'
['17'] => string'Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Range'
['18'] => string'Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Cache-Control, Content-Encoding, Content-Range'
}
```

I have only FTP-access to hosting.

What i need to try?

p.s. saving to disk from site, where button is placed - working correctly.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are depending on the Drive SDK and you have credentials, you cannot use an origin wildcard for the Access-Control header. You'll have to change this source to specify your server address as a source.